# Help Calculating Velocity and displacement from accelerator readings

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an excel table of readings taken from an single axis accelerator placed on a shaker table.

The first column of the table is the time - in seconds increasing in 0.0025 increments. In the second column i have the acceleration at that point in G. I would like to add a third column listing the velocity and a fourth column listing displacement.

I'm not quite sure what formular to use. The answer can be in any units.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to assume the acceleration is constant in each time interval.  If your time step is $\Delta t$ you have $$v(t+\Delta t)=v(t)+a(t)\Delta t\\s(t+\Delta t)=s(t)+v(t)\Delta t + \frac 12a(t)\Delta t^2$$
This is sensitive to systematic error.  If the accelerometer always reads a little high that will integrate to large velocity and position errors.  A first correction would be to note that at the end of the test you are back where you started and at zero velocity, so subtract off a constant acceleration to make the ending location match the beginning location and zero velocity.  You may have to make a compromise there depending on other errors.